# Custom Markers in Distance Services are not working while using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am using HTML5 Geolocation API in which I map the route between client current position and the final position. I used Distance Services API which displays the route but the problem is that I am unable to change the default markers.

When I used "suppressMarkers: true" then default markers hide but none of custom markers are displaying.

Here is my js:

```
var icons = {
    start: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        // URL
        'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/man.png',
        new google.maps.Size(44, 32),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new google.maps.Point(22, 32)
    ),
    end: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        // URL
        'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/police.png',
        new google.maps.Size(44, 32),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new google.maps.Point(22, 32)
    )
};


function Init() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        var options = {
            frequency: 3000,
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            maximumAge: 30000,
            time: 27000
        };
        watchProcess = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(geolocation_query, handle_errors, options);
    } else {
        alert("Geolocation services are not supported by your web browser.");
    }
}

function geolocation_query(position) {
    if (CltLatitude == null || CltLatitude == "")
        if (CltLongitude == null || CltLongitude == "") {
            CltLatitude = position.coords.latitude + (Math.random() / 10 * ((2.55 % 2) ? 1 : -1));
            CltLongitude = position.coords.longitude + (Math.random() / 10 * ((2.54 % 2) ? 1 : -1));
        }

    var currentPos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    var clientLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(CltLatitude, CltLongitude);

    var mapp = {
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: currentPos
    };
    var mapCanvas = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapp);
    var rendererOptions = {
        map: mapCanvas,
        suppressMarkers: true
    };

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

    directionsDisplay.setMap(mapCanvas);
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, currentPos, clientLoc);

}


function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, curentLoc, clntNLocation) {

    directionsService.route({
        origin: curentLoc,
        destination: clntNLocation,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, function(response, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            var leg = response.routes[0].legs[0];
            makeMarker(leg.start_location, icons.start, "Start");
            makeMarker(leg.end_location, icons.end, 'End');
        } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
    });
}


function makeMarker(position, icon, title) {
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: title
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', Init);
```

Tell me where I am doing mistake or missing something?

I tried a lot but none of them worked.. THanks in advance

Comment: `google.maps.MarkerImage` has been deprecated since 2012, you should use [Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Icon) instead

Comment: Just by formatting your code for readability, I can see you've got what looks like an extra closing `}` at the end of your Init function, which might be causing you errors.

Comment: @duncan i removed the extra bracket but still this problem remains..
Can u tell me how to use Marker through "Icon" ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24794891/492335

Comment: Yes, you should suppress the markers and add your own markers afterwards.  Here is an example of about the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26462222/changing-titles-of-endpoint-markers-in-a-google-maps-route/26463019#26463019

Comment: i tried the same but i am not successfull ... Same scenario occurs

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem was that "map" attribute was "undefined" at the marker display place. No need to set "suppressMarkers" to true. I have updated the place of "map" where it is not "undefined". Rest of the code is correct.

```
function geolocation_query(position) {

if (CltLatitude == null || CltLatitude == "")
    if (CltLongitude == null || CltLongitude == "") {
        CltLatitude = position.coords.latitude + (Math.random() / 10 * ((2.55 % 2) ? 1 : -1));
        CltLongitude = position.coords.longitude + (Math.random() / 10 * ((2.54 % 2) ? 1 : -1));
    }

var currentPos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
var clientLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(CltLatitude, CltLongitude);

var mapp = {
    zoom: 14,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: currentPos
};
var mapCanvas = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapp);
var rendererOptions = {
    map: mapCanvas
 // no need to set "supress to true"
};

var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

directionsDisplay.setMap(mapCanvas);


directionsService.route({
    origin: currentPos,
    destination: clntNLoc,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
}, function (response, status) {

    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        startMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: currentPos,
            icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/man.png',
            map: mapCanvas,
            title: 'Start'
        });
        endMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: clntNLoc,
            icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/police.png',
            map: mapCanvas,
            title: 'End'
        });
    } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
  }
```

If any query then inform me.

Comment: One more update is that it works fine also when suppressMarkers is set to be true. I tested it

Answer (score 0):

I get a javascript error with your code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined` (and `Uncaught ReferenceError: CltLatitude is not defined` but that isn't likely the problem).

Your problem is that there is no `map` variable in your code (you use `mapCanvas`), so the makeMarker function never adds the marker to your map:

```
function makeMarker(position, icon, title) {
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: title
    });
}
```

either pass the reference to the map into that function (you will need to pass it down the call stack):

```
function makeMarker(position, icon, title, map) {
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: title
    });
}
```

or make the `mapCanvas` variable global and change the `makeMarker` function to use it:

```
function makeMarker(position, icon, title) {
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: mapCanvas,
        icon: icon,
        title: title
    });
}
```

Comment: i answered my question and @geocodezip variable declaration is understood. I declared at my side but in question I skipped. Try my solution